Matching question types and answer types in quiz module
There are question types and answer types in the Quiz module. I am particularly interested in the question type Long answer question and the answer type Long answer response. In the answer type, I have added a few fields to answer the questions in more detail.
My idea was that the same answer type should be applied to a question type. So if I create a question of the type Long answer question, I thought that the type Long answer response would also be applied to it in the quiz. However, I do not see the additional fields that I have created in the answers.
Am I misunderstanding the principle or are there special configurations to consider that I haven't found yet?

I don't know the details of the Quiz module, but using fields for questions and answers seems like a very bad idea for performance.  Say you added 30 quizzes with 5 questions each, (if revisions are enabled) you now have 600 database tables (30 quizzes * (5 questions * 2 for revisions + 5 answers * 2 for revisions). I would instead look for a module like Webform that does not create standard Drupal fields.

It seems also a bad idea to edit a question to add answers. I would take Stack Exchange sites as example: When I add an answer, I do not need to edit the question.
